# mysql workbench can't write to sql history file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm running mysql workbench on my local machine, connected to a remote sql server.

I am able to apply changes to the database, however, I see this error every time I apply a change

I can't seem to find any help online regarding this error, so I can't provide any more details

`Error: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.`

and in the message log 
`ERROR: Can't write to SQL history file`

Answer (score 0):

The `sql_history` directory under `~/.mysql/workbench` was owned by root. I'm not sure how that happened in a default install.

However, running `sudo chown -R <username>:<group> ~/.mysql/workbench/sql_history` did the trick